# JS: Autoselecting HTML <option> tags via querySelector does not trigger AJAX requests to server?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to autocomplete forms on a website with javascript injections in a Chrome extension. I have been using `.querySelector` to "select" options in HTML dropdown menus. For some menus on this target site, the options are generated via ajax once a user has selected an option. `.querySelector` is not correctly replicating some kind of behavior that coaxes the AJAX response; basically, I'm unable to complete the HTML forms because nothing has triggered the source jquery which populates `<select>` tags with options.

The form I'm trying to autoselect looks something like this

```
<select name="traveling_to[0]" id="traveling_toSelect0" class="travelingToSelect" >
    //a bunch of option values
</select>
```

The source javascript on the target site is like this (abridged...):

```
$( '.travelingToSelect' ).change( function( e )
    {           
        var destination = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        if( ! destination || destination.length == 0 )
            return;

        //some more conditions here on the site...

        var postData = {
            destination: destination,
            nationality: nationality,
            state: state_of_residence,
            localCode: 'EN'
        };
            $.get( '/ajax/ajax.fillPurposes2.php', postData, function( data ) {
                for( var n in data ) {
                    var newPurpose = document.createElement( 'option' );
                    newPurpose.value = data[n].Code;
                    newPurpose.innerHTML = data[n].Name;
                    newPurpose.title = data[n].Name;
                    newPurpose.description = data[n].Description;
                    target.appendChild( newPurpose );

                //etc...
```

And the short code I've been using to select HTML options:

```
function selectOption(formId, selectFormId, HTMLOptionValue) {
    var a = document.getElementById(formId);
    a.querySelector("#"+selectFormId).value = HTMLOptionValue
}
```

How can I trigger this `.change` jquery function with a javascript injection?

edit: I've tried running the `selectOption` function several times between options, and tried using `setTimeout` to let the site load all its scripts, but these workarounds have not worked.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `querySelector`. Assigning to `.value` doesn't trigger the `change` event, no matter how you get the element.

Comment: Is there any way to trigger `.change`?

Comment: The usual recommendation is to put the change handler in a named function, and then just call it directly after assigning to `.value`.

Comment: You can also use `$('#'+selectFormId).trigger('change')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, I'll look into them.